# How can i add a list of items to offline storage?

Tags: javascript

Ι have form, with text-box and a button.

I can add the name of some countries inside the text box and by pressing the add button, the names are added to an unordered list.
I also have a delete button next to each new element to delete them.

I want to activate offline storage.
I have added some items to the list and after reloading the page those items should stay there in the list.

I don't know how to get access my list through localStorage.SetItem and also how to retrieve those items. here is my code. need some help. Thank you

---

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

To set to local storage: `localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');`

To get from local storage: `const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');`

For more info [(Mozilla - Dev) LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

You should probable need to use the `onLoad` event, to check if the value exists in local storage while your script is loading.

Check here: [W3 - OnLoad](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addToList(countryName){
  const item={name:countryName}
 countryList.push(item)
 localStorage.setItem("elements-list",(JSON.stringify(countryTxt)))
}

var elements_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('elements-list'));
```